# How to pass container name with k8s.io client-go rest API request

Tags: go, kubernetes, containers, client-go

How to pass container name information for Kubernetes k8s.io client-go app:

```
    execReq = client.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Name(solrPod).
        Namespace(brConfig.solrOptions.Namespace).
        SubResource("exec").
        SubResource("solr").
        VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
            Command: []string{"java", "CorruptFile", "/opt/solr/data"},
            Stdin:   true,
            Stdout:  true,
            Stderr:  true,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)
```

like -

```
kubectl -n namespace exec pod-name -c container-name.
```

How to pass the container-name via client-go?

Answer (score 1):

I dug through this for a while . It's an option in your [parameters](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#query-parameters-17), also [here](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodExecOptions):

```golang
execReq = client.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
    Resource("pods").
    Name(solrPod).
    Namespace(brConfig.solrOptions.Namespace).
    SubResource("exec").
    SubResource("solr").
    VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
        Command: []string{"java", "CorruptFile", "/opt/solr/data"},
        Container: []string("containername"), 
        Stdin:   true,
        Stdout:  true,
        Stderr:  true,
    }, scheme.ParameterCodec)
```

✌️☮️